# How to force og:image to be cropped from bottom?

Tags: wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I have trouble with facebook, twitter, mix.com basically with every social site. When I share my post all my images are automatically cropped from the center leaving peoples on images headless. How to force og:image to be cropped from the bottom only leaving the upper part of the image visible? I am using WordPress theme GeneratePress.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are following the guidelines: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/images

> - The minimum allowed image dimension is 200 x 200 pixels.
> - The size of the image file must not exceed 8 MB.
> - Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels for the best display on high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that
>     are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images.
> - ...

If you make sure to use the correct aspect ratio, you can limit the chance of getting cropped images:

> **Try to keep your images as close to 1.91:1 aspect ratio as possible to display the full image in News Feed without any cropping.**